# MYSQL hide field data if value in another field is set

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, where-clause, data-representation

Got a table like:

```
art.    type    price
a        b       1
a        c       2
```

would it be possible with a select to show filtered content as:

```
art.    type    price
a        b       
a        c       2
```

so that if the type is "b" don't show price data?

```
select art, type, price from x 
where type="b" hide price
```

Comment: what is the condition that decide if a field should be hidden or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic of this sort probably best belongs in the presentation, rather than database, layer of your application.  However, it is nevertheless possible using either MySQL's [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function or its [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression—for example:

```
SELECT art, type, IF(type='b',NULL,price) price FROM x;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66fc7/1/0).