# MySQL - IF statement to hide a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that uses a radio button, this button decides if it shows a piece of data or not:

```
<input type="radio" name="IncludeData" value="1" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="IncludeData" value="0" />No
```

Yes = 1 and No = 0.

I'm then using this query to call the data:

```
$IncludeData = $_POST['IncludeData'];
$sql = "SELECT data1, data2, data3, IF($IncludeData='0',Null,data4), data4, data5 FROM Database ORDER BY data1 asc";
```

I've tried following the answer from this question: [MYSQL hide field data if value in another field is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659065/mysql-hide-field-data-if-value-in-another-field-is-set).

However, it always seems to keep the data no matter what I select on the radio button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is where I grab the data from:

```
<td>
Sort table on =
<select name="Sort">
<option value="data1" selected="selected">Example1</option>
<option value="data2">Example2</option>
<option value="data3">Example3</option>
<option value="data4">Example4</option>
<option value="data5">Example5</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Comment: You have `data4` in the field after that as well. So when you select `No`, you'll get `data1, data2, data3, NULL, data4, data5`, and when you select `Yes` you'll get `data1, data2, data3, data4, data4, data5`.

Comment: Maybe you meant that to be an alias for this `IF`, so it should be `IF(...) AS data4`.

Comment: I thought that at first too @Barmar. But when I removed `data4` from after the IF statement, nothing showed at all. Not even when I selected yes...

Comment: How are you showing this field? Have you given an alias to the `IF()` so that you can refer to it by name?

Comment: You need to post more code so we can see how you're accessing the result of the query.

Comment: Just added the code to where I grab the data from @Barmar

Comment: Please, please, don't ever embed user-provided variables directly into your SQL query. (I hope this was only for demonstration purposes!) See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Don't worry @alttag ! This is demo purposes only. Thank you though :)

Comment: @thickguru I meant the code that processes the result of the query, e.g. `$data4 = $row['data4']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?:

```
$IncludeData = $_POST['IncludeData'] ? 'data4, ' : '';
$sql = "SELECT data1, data2, data3, $IncludeData data5 FROM Table ORDER BY data1 ASC";
```

Comment: you beat me to it

Comment: Sorry but no. `$IncludeData` is not associated to the field, it is only associated to 0 and 1. So yes the data is included, or no, the data is not.

Comment: I know, with that code if $includeData is 1, data4 column will be included and if $includeData is 0, data4 won't be included...

Comment: Sorry! Mis-read it the first time! That worked like a dream. Thank you very much